# Accessing Macro enabled file using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have macro enabled Excel files and I want to consolidate the values from these files into a new file. I wrote the following macro, which navigates to the specific cells in each file and sums it up into a new consolidated file.

```
Sub SumWB()
  Dim Arr(2) As Long, MyWB As Workbook, fStr As String
  Const Folder = "C:\Users\user123\Downloads\New folder\"
  file = Dir(Folder)
  While (file <> "")

    If file <> "Consolidated.xlsm" Then
       Set MyWB = Workbooks.Open(Folder & file, , True)
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("B4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("C4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("D4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("E4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("E4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("F4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("F4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("G4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("G4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("H4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("H4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("I4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("I4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("J4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("J4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("K4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("K4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("L4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("L4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("M4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("M4").Value
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("N4") = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(1).Range("N4").Value
       MyWB.Save
       MyWB.Close
    End If
    file = Dir
  Wend

End Sub
```

I get `Run time error '13' : Type Mismatch`. The error points towards the Range("C4") line.

Another problem is, once the macro enabled file is opened, while saving it, "`the file is a read only. To save a copy, click OK, then give the workbook a new name in the Save as dialog box`". Which defeats the purpose of automating the entire process. Because I didn't want to manually open and close all these files. Is there a way I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just pulling info out of the files, I'm not sure why you would need to save them.  Since you're opening them read only, that prevents you from saving and generates that message.  I would just remove the `myWB.Save` line.  If it still ends up prompting to save changes, replace `myWB.Close` with `myWB.Close(False)` to close without saving changes.

Regarding the type mismatch, is it possible that the value from the workbook is not a number?  (adding `5 + "5 "` will result in a type mismatch instead of `10`)

Comment: all the values in the cell are 1 only. Is there a way we find which cell is not a number? The range from B4:N4 is 1 only. for testing purpose I have kept it like that and the consolidated file has 0s in the same B4:N4 range. Still I am getting the mismatch error in the C4 line of the code.

P.S while this error is occuring, in the background, I can see the values from the file. Once I close the error and debugging, the value disappear

Comment: Likely the best thing to do would be to test the value from `MyWB` via the `IsNumeric` function before adding it. Alternatively, when it goes into debug mode, look at what workbook `MyWB` is, then look at the value for C4 on Sheet1 to see if you can get an idea of what's going on.